# In magento, in "Customer Grid", how can I fix to show data in "Name" column in all records?

Tags: name, customer-grid

In magento "Customer Grid", data in "Name" column is missing in some rows and showing in some rows. How can I fix to show data in "Name" column in all records?
[image]

Comment: make sure on that record there is data are present

Comment: in customer detail page, last name is missing. All the records that miss last name in customer detail page do not show data in Name column. How can I proceed to retrieve last name in detail page. The problem is that last name is presented in some and not presented in some also.

Answer (score 1):

Magento `customer name in Customer grid`   is `depends on addNameToSelect function` on  c`lass Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection`.
So,they may create issue on

1)`on function addNameToSelect` this field value comes with concatenate with 
`prefix+firstname+middlename+lastname+suffix`.
logic

```
a)prefix(optional depends on setting )
b)firstname
c)middlenameoptional depends on setting )
d)lastname
e)suffix(optional depends on setting )
```

it may be issue with this.

2) `database issue in some data`.

**Alternative Solution:**

show `first name and last name in individual  columns`.

**step1**:Just copy `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php` to
Copy this file to `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php`.

**Step2**: on `_prepareColumns` just add code below code:

```
$this->addColumn('firstname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
        'index'     => 'firstname'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
        'index'     => 'lastname'
    ));
```

Comment: But I would like to show only "Name" column. I do not want to show individual columns of first name and last name. The problem why "Name" data is missing is that data in "Last Name" field is missing in customer detail page.

Comment: magento must throw error if customer did not have last name.it may some customization on your system

Comment: if you want to show it on grid then copy app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer/Collection.php to app/code/loal/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer/Collection.php just commit  $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{lastname}}))';

Comment: In customer registration, customers put their first name and last name and then click "Save". Registration is successful but in "Customer detail page of Customer grid", last name is missing. How can I control to this problem? Thank you so much for giving me your time Amit Bera.

Comment: then.... check system.log and exception log where actual issue for not saving last name in db.put this code question

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem. About 2 months ago i imported 130 customers and today trying to import but the Name in Customer Grid column is missing. I tried to add manually but still not working. Really strange that on old customers Names are there and on this no. Can you somebody help? see screenshot[image]